# ¿Por que no se cumple la condicion en este codigo? Ayuda

Tags: javascript

```
 myApp.controller('lUnidadesController',function($scope){
    var data = [
            {clave:"1", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "1", cambiar: "  "},       
            {clave:"1", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"2", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"3", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"4", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"5", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"6", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "x", cambiar: "  "}
    ];
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            dato = value.estatus;
            console.log(dato);
            if(dato=="disponible"){    
             template='<img src="static/images/sports-car.svg" alt="Vehiculo" width=20 height=20>';
            }else{
                template="<p>none</p>";
            }

        });
        var obj = {
            columnBorders: true,
            editable:false,
            stripeRows: true,        
            width: "100%",
            height: 800,
            colModel: [
                { title: "Clave", dataIndx: "clave" },
                { title: "Nombre", dataIndx: "nombre" },
                { title: "Agencia", dataIndx: "agencia" },
                { title: "Sector", dataIndx: "sector" },
                { title: "Estatus", dataIndx: "estatus" },
                { title: "Actualizacion", align: 'center', editable:false,template:template}
            ],
            resizable: true,
            numberCell: {show: false},  
            scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
            selectionModel: { type: 'row', mode: 'block' },

            dataModel: { data: data }
        };
         function asignacionColor(){    
             for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){  
                if(data[i].estatus=="disponible"){
                    data[i].pq_rowcls='green';
                }else{
                    data[i].pq_rowcls='red';
                }

            }

        }


        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    asignacionColor();
                    $scope.gridModel = obj;


        });
    });
```

¿Por que en el if en el $.each siempre me sale que no cumple la condición cuando en el objeto data lo declaro igual?

Acepto comentarios[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi me funciona, aquí imprimo la variable template y si entra en la condición https://jsfiddle.net/ozpfwq5f/1/

Comment: Pero al final me pinta puro none en la vista :(

Comment: Eso es porque cuando acaba el ciclo template queda igual a none que es lo que mandas a tu vista.

Comment: Entonces como me recomiendas ? para que respete la condición y no pase esto

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.controller('lUnidadesController',function($scope){
    var data = [
            {clave:"1", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "1", cambiar: "  "},       
            {clave:"1", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"2", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"3", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"4", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"5", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "},
            {clave:"6", nombre: "Andres Diaz", agencia: "Agencia-1", sector: "sector-1", estatus: "disponible", cambiar: "  "}
    ];

        var obj = {
            columnBorders: true,
            editable:false,
            stripeRows: true,        
            width: "100%",
            height: 800,
            colModel: [
                { title: "Clave", dataIndx: "clave" },
                { title: "Nombre", dataIndx: "nombre" },
                { title: "Agencia", dataIndx: "agencia" },
                { title: "Sector", dataIndx: "sector" },
                { title: "Estatus", dataIndx: "estatus" },
                { title: "Actualizacion", align: 'center', editable:false, dataIndx:"template"}
            ],
            resizable: true,
            numberCell: {show: false},  
            scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
            selectionModel: { type: 'row', mode: 'block' },

            dataModel: { data: data }
        };

         function asignacionColor(){    
             for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){  
                if(data[i].estatus=="disponible"){
                    data[i].pq_rowcls='green';
                }else{
                    data[i].pq_rowcls='red';
                }

            }

        }
        function asignacionIcono(){
            template = '<img src="static/images/sports-car.svg" alt="vehiculo" width=20 heigth=20>';
            templateNone='no Exitoso';
            for(var i =0; i<data.length;i++){
               if(data[i].estatus=="disponible"){
                    data[i].template=template;
                }else{
                    data[i].template="";
                } 
            }
        }



        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    asignacionIcono();
                    asignacionColor();
                    console.log(obj);
                    $scope.gridModel = obj;



        });
    });
```

De esta forma quedo solucionado.
Gracias.